# What is monogame supposed to be?

Tags: monogame

What is monogame supposed to be? There is not much info on their homepage http://monogame.net/ and I am not familiar with XNA.

I saw that is uses OpenTK so I assume that it is higher level than OpenGL. Does it sit in between OpenGL and a Game Engine? Could it be compared with Ogre3D?

And what exactly is the content pipeline. I am asking because I am almost exclusively developing on linux and I don't want to install a virtual windows machine only to compile some assets. Is the content pipeline optional?

Comment: Monogame implements XNA, is probably the best way to put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XNA was Microsoft's .NET DirectX 9 wrapper for Windows, Windows Phone and the XBOX 360 (through Xbox Live Indy Games). Aside from providing a DX wrapper, XNA provided content management, helpful classes (game window with draw / update loop and asset management, user input (keyboard, mouse, game controller), networking, etc. It was an excellent framework.

MonoGame is a cross-platform reimplementation of XNA, that does a great job of providing all of the XNA functionality, plus support for DirectX 10 and 11, as well as cross-platform support (via OpenGL/OpenTK) for OSX, Linux, iOS, Android, PlayStation, and others. If you're writing a cross-platform game, it's really worth your time to investigate MonoGame and see if it's right for you.

**Edit**
It's worth noting that neither XNA for MonoGame really qualify as a "game engine." For instance, they don't provide out-of-the-box collision detection, pathfinding, etc. It's up to you to develop those.

If you're looking for a full engine, consider Unity. It's scripting language is C#, and it's used by a significant number of professional game studios.